# Why is my cat meowing so much?

Tags: cats, behavior

Our cat is about two years old and we got her from a shelter. Recently has been meowing almost non-stop as soon as she sees us, unless she's relaxed, like when we're petting or brushing her. I feel like we give her enough attention; we love our kitty!

I've also noticed she meows even more when I'm in the kitchen making food.

They sound like "happy" meows (soft, higher-pitched in tone). It doesn't sound like or seem like she's in any pain or discomfort.

Is it because she wants attention? Or wants a sample of what I'm preparing? Is there something she is trying to tell us? Should I even be concerned?

Comment: Has anything about your home or living conditions recently changed?

Comment: Our roommate got a puppy a couple months ago. They get along, but at times the puppy wants to play and she doesn't, and he doesn't get the hint until after a few smacks from her and scolding from us. The excessive mewing has only started within the past couple of weeks or so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you've indicated that you've recently added a new puppy, it sounds like she's just in a period of adjustment. This has happened in our house when we've brought home new arrivals. Once they realize the new kitten isn't going anywhere, there's a period of trying to reassert their place in the household.

If nothing else has changed about her behavior (eating, drinking, hiding, etc), then it's likely just a gentle, "hey, I'm still here", like an older child acting out when mommy brings home the new baby.